# pd.read_table() can#t read my first row and read it as name or column index

Tags: python, pandas

I use `y_train_df = pd.read_table('y_train.txt')` to read my txt train file, but it can only be read like this,

```
      5
0     5
1     5
2     5
3     5
4     5
...  ..
7762  2
7763  2
7764  2
7765  2
7766  2
```

then I use `y_train_df = pd.read_table(base_datadir + 'Train/y_train.txt', header=None, index_col=False)`, to make `header=none` and `index_col=False`, but it still can't read the first row, the first value `5` is changed to `0`.

```
      0
0     5
1     5
2     5
3     5
4     5
...  ..
7762  2
7763  2
7764  2
7765  2
7766  2
```

Not sure how this happened, can somebody help to tell what went wrong here?

same problem for my another txt file:
[image]

here is how y_train.txt looks like:

```
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
...
2
2
2
2
2
```

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the `y_train.txt` as text so that I can fine tune my answer?

Comment: yeah, i have edited, it is an array [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, ..., 2, 2 , 2], it is the activity label in HAPT dataset.

Comment: Cool. Just edited my answer to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when the `header=None` is passed, the `read_table` function disregards the actual first column as the header. Hence, it returns integers: `0, 1, 2, ...` as the headers. When the `header=None` is not passed, the first column automatically becomes the header.

---

Post the edit: When the `header=None` is passed, the DataFrame returned would have 7767 rows. In this manner, the header becomes a list of integers `0,1,2,...`. However, when `header=None` is not passed, the first columns becomes the header, and the number of rows in the DataFrame returned would become 7766 (and we would loose out on the first column inadvertently)

For more information, you could check the [documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html).

Comment: how can I correct this? I want the 7767 rows result...

Comment: You'd just need to add `header=None`. In this manner, all the entries are taken into consideration :)

Comment: Did this help solve your problem and answer your doubt?

Answer (score 1):

How about read all data just in one column, then process data-cleaning?

```py
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_str = '''
      5 2
0     5 1
1     5 1
2     5 1
3     5 1
4     5 1
7762  2 1
7763  2 1
7764  2 1
7765  2 1
7766  2 3
'''

obj = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_str.strip()), sep='\n', header=None)[0]
objn = obj.str.split('\s+')
objn.iloc[0].insert(0, '')
df = pd.DataFrame(objn.str[1:].tolist())

print(df)
```

output:

```
    0  1
0   5  2
1   5  1
2   5  1
3   5  1
4   5  1
5   5  1
6   2  1
7   2  1
8   2  1
9   2  1
10  2  3
```

Comment: I may not make it too clear, the first ```5``` is the part of the data, but it was read as a column name, I don't want it to be a column name or column index.

Comment: @SuperEiskalt I know what you mean, you see, the raw data has 11 rows, the first row is 5,2. You can try replacing `io.StringIO(df_str.strip()` with a file name. Test it and seek the output.